# Does anyone know what header file is missing?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

This code works on Code Blocks but not on Visual Studio:

```
// A simple program that prints string test1:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    vector<string> test1 = { "pooping","reading" };


    for (vector<string>::iterator iter = test1.begin(); iter != test1.end(); iter++)
    {
        cout << *iter << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

The error that Visual Studio Outputs:

```
Error   C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<std::_Simple_types<std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: @JerryCoffin << still the same error even with asterisk

Comment: Looking more carefully, you want the asterisk *and* you're missing a header (`<string>`).

Comment: @JerryCoffin Yep, works now when I put header string. I was just wondering why the code worked in Codeblocks (without header string)  and not visual studio..... probably a bug in Code Blocks

Comment: @piyushj Nope, not that one.

Comment: Not exactly a bug (or not in the compiler, anyway). Any standard header is allowed to include any or all others (but it's not required, so you want to include the ones you use, even if the compiler you're using works without it).

Answer (score 1):

`std::basic_string` is officially defined in the `<string>` header. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<string>
```

The class template basic_string stores and manipulates sequences of char-like objects. The class is dependent neither on the character type nor on the nature of operations on that type. The definitions of the operations are supplied via the Traits template parameter - a specialization of std::char_traits or a compatible traits class. For more details please see 
[std::basic_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score -1):

after adding  header , program won't compile and it will throw error

```
"error: in C++98 'test1' must be initialized by constructor, not by '{...}'"
```

check the below program followed another method to initialize vector.

As suggested by other you need to add

```
      #include<string>
```

// A simple program that prints string test1:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
 #include<string>

 using namespace std;

 int main()

 {
 static const string arr[] = {"pooping","reading"};
vector<string> test1 (arr, arr + sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) );

for (vector<string>::iterator iter = test1.begin(); iter != test1.end(); iter++)
{
    cout << *iter << endl;
}
system("pause");
 }
```